# Crontab log data while running python script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron, raspberry-pi

I am working on some code and I want to log output and inputs from crontab

My code is continuous which is in while True type loop

```
import time
while(1):
    print "testing"
    time.sleep(5)
```

In Crontab I've written following

```
@reboot python /home/Desktop/Application.py >> /home/Desktop/log_file 2>&1
```

I know removing continuous while loop will work. But My application is a sort of that needs a continuous while loop

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note. Have you thought about using the native logging library ?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: I've not tried this.. Thanks @BenoîtZu